# C Run-Time CRT vs C++ Run-Time - heap memory management model

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory

Is there a C runtime Librairies and a C++ runtime Librairies  or is there only a C runtime (i.e: therefore C++ programs use the C Run-Time, maybe there is also a c++ Run-Time library and C++ use both C and C++ Run-Time Librairies)

Secondly, if there exist both a C and a C++ runtime, does the C++ heap memory management model is the same than the C heap memory management used by the CRT (namley use of linked list for block of memory) ?

EDIT:

Thirdly, if a C++ program use the CRT, does it mean that there is two heap for the program? one used by the CRT and one used by the C++ Run-Time ?

Comment: Would help to mention tool chain or OS.

Comment: @brian: acutally I don't talk about a particular plateform, I mean generally what is the practice.

Comment: But the answer is different for different platforms and the standard leave this open to implementation variation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually for C++ programs, they have a distinct runtime, but that runtime is implemented on top of the C run-time, so they delegate as much work as they can- and memory management is a fairly simple one. The only thing C++ has to do on top of C is deal with exceptions, destructors, and whatnot- the actual memory allocation itself can come right from `malloc`. However, the Standard does not guarantee this at all and it can't be relied upon.

Comment: so in pratice a `new` call ended by a `malloc` call ?

Comment: Yes, `new` is quite often implemented as `malloc` (and `delete` would then end up using `free` to deallocate, of course), or some common lower level allocation function in some cases. But don't rely on this, C++ `new` may well do something completely different "because it's a good opportunity to do something different"

Comment: Calling free() on something obtained by new, or calling delete on something obtained by malloc are very bad ideas.

Comment: @Brian: that is not what Mats said

Comment: @guillaume07: actually, since new does more than just allocation, and free more than deallocation, even if they do use malloc and free under the covers, it's _still_ not safe to mix malloc and free!

Answer (score 2):

There is an oddity with heaps on Windows.  If a DLL statically links in the C run time, then that DLL gets its own heap.  So if you have 5 DLL like this then your process has at least 5 heaps.  And you need to be really careful to call free() in the same DLL that called malloc() (or delete / new).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are talking about the same compiler suite (like GCC, or Visual C++, for example), there is usually a C and C++ runtime, with the C runtime also being used for C++ programs if/when you are using C functions.

Usually, the memory management of the C++ runtime is making use of the C runtime memory management, but this is by no means a given and shouldn't be relied on. After all, there usually isn't much of a point of reimplementing a complete heap manager if you can add another interface to an existing implementation.

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ doesn't define how "heaps" work other than the public interfaces, such as `malloc`, `new`, `free` and `delete` and some siblings of these. Each compiler/library vendor will make their own (and yes, you CAN use a library that isn't part of part of the compiler suite, for example gcc MingW uses the Microsoft Libraries to a large extent).

I'm not sure it makes much sense to worry about if there is one heap, two heaps, three heaps or a thousand heaps - as long as you can allocate memory from whichever one is relevant for your code, it's really an implementation detail how many heaps there are - and I see very few cases where the number of them would matter - other than the tiny bit of admin overhead that each heap has, perhaps. But that would be in the order of a few dozen bytes or so, unless someone has really gone overboard with the heap design.

As mentioned elsewhere, the C++ code may or may not use the same heap or have a separate heap. Again, it makes no difference to your code. As long as when you free it, you use the same method as when you allocated - that is, don't use `new` to allocate something, and `free` to free it, or `malloc` and `delete`. That would be very bad - even if the data comes from the same heap, you may well find that there is "hidden" information stored by `new` to track the data, that is different from what `malloc` has stashed away, which means that `malloc` doesn't "understand" what's going on, and weird crashes occur!

Comment: multiple heaps can make a difference.  Memory allocated from one must be freed to the same heap..

Comment: Yes, which is why I said "you need to release the memory with the matching method as you allocated it". Hopefully, no one designs an interface to a function that uses a "private" (or "separate") heap that requires that you call free() on it... That would be rather daft!

Comment: No, I mean, if you have a static library that allocates memory with `new`, then you _cannot_ safely use `delete` on it from your code.  It's _technically_ not the matching method, despite all appearances otherwise.  That's more of a C interface problem though, C++ usually uses smart pointers to bypass the problem.

Comment: Yes, and my point is that if the static library has a "create stuff" calling new, it should also have a corresponding "destroy stuff" function that frees it up. Otherwise, whoever came up with the idea in the first place ought to be punished for the idea.